# Insert one image into another using a mac command line tool

Tags: macos, cocoa, imagemagick, sips

I've been looking various options to allow me to automate processing of some images.

I've looked at sips, which doesn't seem to provide an option for this.

Also I've considered writing a mac app to do this, however I can't find much example code which would do everything I need.

I've also looked at ImageMagik which seems to have this feature, but I can't find an example.

I wondered if anyone had acheived this and if do, could point me at an example.
Alternatively a different tool which would allow me to do this?

Failing this a good source of mac cocoa source which would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of examples here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/ - for example

```
     composite -compose Copy -gravity South  hand_point.gif   rose:   -alpha set   compose_copy.gif
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for point insertion method. ImageMagik seems amazing, but the documentation is so extensive it's going to take me just as long to either use a manual graphics app or write a mac app. Sigh. I guess I really need to learn to use a specific graphics app. As will also need to add text, rotate etc, which will all take time to configure for each image. I'm up voting this for now, will award in a few days. Thanks.

Comment: For me half the issue is layout of the documentation - like the sample images are too small and the lack of white space etc.